# Start second match from offset of first match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I need link the second match from last offset of previous match. Imagine that I have:

```
id, name
```

I will use `preg_match_all()` to capture `id` and `name` (comma splitted), so I can use something [**LIKE THIS**](http://regex101.com/r/qW8wQ6/1):

```
\s* (\w+) \s* (?:,|$)
```

It will works fine with my previous example. But if I do:

```
invalid example
```

It'll match `example`. And I don't want to match in this case, because I need accept only if ALL data is matched by something (spaces is group not allowed on my regex).

To solve this problem, I supposedly can use the start of line anchor, [**LIKE THIS**](http://regex101.com/r/mM3xS0/1):

```
^ \s* (\w+) \s* (?:,|$)
```

So my previous example will not match now (it's right), but my first example will fail, because `name` will not match, once that it don't is start of line.

**Examples**:

- `id` need match only `id`;
- `id, name` need match `id` and `name`;
- `will fail` need fail;
- `will, fail too` need fail, too;

[**More examples here..**](http://regex101.com/r/tH9oQ2/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex for matching all the inputs either followed by `,` OR end of input  using `preg_match_all` function:

```
[^,] +.*$(*SKIP)(*F)|(\w+)(?=(?:, \w+)*$)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xZ5sF4/1)

Comment: Is not viable for me, because I have some groups, and I need capture some infos about each matched part.

Comment: Didn't get your comment, what is not viable with the provided answer?

Comment: [Check it](http://pastebin.com/uMTU4eKu), it's my current regular expression. I have a lot of named groups that I capture to set some properties of object (for each matched item).

Comment: @anubhava it seems OP wants to use `\G` here to capture all the matches, but it is not clear.

Comment: Hmm named groups can only work with finite set of inputs. What if your input is `foo, bar, baz, abc, xyz, pqr`? Can your input only have 1 or 2 or 3 elements delimited by `, `?